# Can I call a Struts2 action on click of a html link in html page

Tags: java, html, struts2, struts

I want a Struts2 action to be performed on click of a html link in a html page.
My first question is whether is it possible to perform a Struts2 action in a html page(not JSP)?
If yes, take a look at my code below:

***home.html***

href="home.action"

---

***struts.xml***

> action name="home" class="com.struts.action.HomeAction"
>
> ```
>       result name="Success">loginJSP.jsp
> ```

---

*****web.xml*****
I did filter mapping such that everything goes to Struts2

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```
<a href="<s:url action="actionName"/>">click here</a>
```

Or this?

```
<a href="/abc/actionname.action">Click here</a><br />
```

Also see: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html

Just curious to know, why can't you use JSP?

Comment: Fantastic, both are working. Thanks a lot. I'm porting a huge application to struts and i dint want to change the already existing hundreds of html pages to JSP's.

Comment: No problem Dhora. Please accept the answer if you think this is the right one to gain acceptance ratings.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <s:url action="actionNameInStrutsXML" method="methodNameInYourClass" var="menuAdmin" />
          <s:a href="%{menuAdmin}">Menu</s:a>
```

In this way you can call the method that you prefer.

Remember to put in your struts config this:

> struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"